# Pillow+numpy+unittest gives a ResourceWarning: does this indicate a leak?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library

When I use Pillow (version 3.3.0, installed via pip) on Python3 to load image data into numpy arrays, my unit tests report a `ResourceWarning`.  The warning occurs, for example, when I run the following script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import unittest
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image

def load_image():
    with PIL.Image.open('test.tif') as im:
        return np.array(im)

class TestData(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_PIL(self):
        im = load_image()
        print(im.shape)

unittest.main()
```

The output is

```
./err.py:14: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name='test.tif'>
  im = load_image()
(420, 580)
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.012s

OK
```

(The warning disappears, if I don't wrap the image in a numpy array.)

Does this resource warning indicate a leak in my code (*e.g.*, do I need to "close" the image file somehow beyond using the `with` statement)?  Or, if the warning is spurious, how can I disable it?

Comment: what if you use `np.array(im.getdata())`?

Comment: @WayneWerner using `np.array(im.getdata())` I still get the warning, and also the array is then the wrong shape.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR**, I think this is a bug. This should close the file handle as expected:

```
def load_image():
    with open('test.tif', 'rb') as im_handle:
        im = PIL.Image.open(im_handle)
        return np.array(im)
```

---

Okay, let's check what's actually happening:

For that we add a logger:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import logging
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('hi from the logger!')

import unittest
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image

def load_image():
    with PIL.Image.open('test.tif') as im:
        return np.array(im)

class TestData(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_PIL(self):
        im = load_image()
        print(im.shape)

unittest.main()
```

This is what we get:

```
DEBUG:root:hi from the logger!
/Users/ch/miniconda/envs/sci34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/Image.py:678: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name='test.tif'>
  self.load()
DEBUG:PIL.Image:Error closing: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'
(225, 300, 3)
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.022s

OK
```

`DEBUG:PIL.Image:Error closing: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'` is raised in the close method of the `Image` class:

```
def close(self):
    """
    Closes the file pointer, if possible.

    This operation will destroy the image core and release its memory.
    The image data will be unusable afterward.

    This function is only required to close images that have not
    had their file read and closed by the
    :py:meth:`~PIL.Image.Image.load` method.
    """
    try:
        self.fp.close()
    except Exception as msg:
        logger.debug("Error closing: %s", msg)

    # Instead of simply setting to None, we're setting up a
    # deferred error that will better explain that the core image
    # object is gone.
    self.im = deferred_error(ValueError("Operation on closed image"))
```

To put it in words:

At the end of the `with` block, the `close` method is called. It tries to close the open file handle stored in `self.fp`. But in your case `self.fp` is not a file handle and thus cannot be closed. The closing fails silently.

So when you leave the `with` block, the file handle is not closed and nose's error message is legit.

Comment: Thanks, I agree with your analysis, and your workaround works.  I also looked into filing a bug for Pillow, but they already have several reports which seem to be the same issue, so I just left a note at https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1651 .